# Clear timage.canvas in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How to clear `timage` canvas to avoid duplicate image when changing input size? Why nil command doesn't work?
This is my code

```
 begin 
 image1.Canvas := nil;  
 image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
 image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue; 
 image1.canvas.rectangle(10,10,vwpj,vwlb);        
 end;
```

Comment: Images always contain something. If you wish to fill with a background colour. Do so. Don't dump your entire code on us. Just what we need to see.

Comment: when size change, will make new rectangle behind old rectangle on canvas. please, how the right code i must write?

Comment: @nas He isn't changing the size of anything. He's drawing a rectangle at specific coordinates.

Comment: @rendra I'm amazed this compiles. You should not be able to assign to Canvas. Remove that code.

Comment: this my code before edited image1.Canvas := nil; image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed; image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue; image1.canvas.rectangle(10,10,vwpj,vwlb);

Comment: Dear @DavidHeffernan, now he is panicked because of your comments, he deleted all the necessary code backing up my comment. The main idea of the OP is to draw a new rectangle each time the size changes on the same canvas.

Comment: Remove the assignment to Canvas. Paint a rectangle on it.

Comment: @rendra change the image size as well by doing `image1.height:=vwlb-10;` and  `image1.width:=vwpj-10;`

Comment: @nasreddine, i just don't know how to do right asking in here :)

Comment: You will learn it is a great place to learn do not give up on it, and for further learning on how to ask a good question please see [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @rendra any luck with what I suggested?

Comment: Rendra is a SO beginner and also a Delphi beginner. I welcome Rendra by giving him/her a +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign `Nil` or any value to `Canvas`, `Canvas` is a property for read only, so you need to remove the first line and then draw on the `TImage` canvas:

```
Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
Image1.canvas.rectangle(0,0,Image1.Height,Image1.Width);
```

Edit:
You have to set the image to default every time you draw on it's canvas:

Procedure:

```
Procedure TForm1.Default(Image: TImage);
begin
  Image.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBtnFace;
  Image.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
  Image.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Image.Height,Image.Width));
end;
```

Then call it as:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Default(Image1);
  Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  Image1.canvas.rectangle(0,0,Image1.Height,Image1.Width);
end;
```

[image]

Comment: when use tedit to change width or height of rectangle, why is create new rectangle behind old rectangle, not just change width and height of one rectangle first create?

Comment: @rendra You have to set it to default first (clBtnFace)

Comment: @rendra Can you define what you mean by clearing an image.

Comment: I think you have just inverted height and width for the clean part.  Image.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Image.Height,Image.Width)); must be Image.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Image.Width,Image.Height));

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written and tried to explain in your many previous edits.
This is a possible solution to your problem.

**Requirements:**

1. Add four `TEdit` components to your form.
2. Add one `TButton`.
3. And one `TImage`.

**Code:**

```
var
Xorigin,Yorigin,vwpj,vwlb:integer;
....
begin
  vwpj := strtoint(vwpjEdit.text);
  vwlb := strtoint(vwlbEdit.text);
  Xorigin := strtoint(XoriginEdit.Text);
  Yorigin := strtoint(YoriginEdit.Text);
  // You have to wipe the canvas with a base color,
  image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clwhite;
  image1.Canvas.FillRect(rect(0,0,image1.Width,image1.height));
  image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  image1.Canvas.rectangle(Xorigin,Yorigin,vwlb,vwpj);
end;
```

**Explanation:** I understand that you want to draw a rectangle on the `Canvas` property of a `TImage`. With the condition of each time you resize the rectangle you want to clear the `Canvas` (you implied this by assigning `nil` to canvas which is wrong considering that `Canvas` is a read only property).

Now the above code does this by filling the canvas with a base color (I chose `clwhite`) by using the `Fillrect()` method.

From this you need to understand that there is no such thing as clearing the image, either you delete it (using the `free` command as you say) and it will be gone and if you want to draw on it again you will need to create it.
the second option is that you fill it with a background color (the base `clwhite` I chose) or as a third option, resize the image as well.

All what maters is that as long as that image is still there the canvas and what you have drawn on it will remain.

**Results of the code above**

[image]

[image]

Comment: @kobik one of my teachers when I was little said _sometimes you would think that you are right, but only when someone more experienced than you comes ,you know_; I take the more experienced person is to be you in this case. I will remove that part